# zoom sdk for android: can't join as a host

Tags: java, android, zoom-sdk

i already inputted all the necessary parameters for it to work according to the docs and the forums but it just can't seem to work on me

```
private  void joinMeeting(Context context, String meetingNumber,String zak, String userName, String usID){
        int ret = -1;
        MeetingService meetingService = ZoomSDK.getInstance().getMeetingService();
        JoinMeetingOptions options = new JoinMeetingOptions();
        //JoinMeetingParams params = new JoinMeetingParams();
        //params.displayName=userName;
        //params.meetingNo =meetingNumber;
        //params.password=meetingPassword;
        //meetingService.joinMeetingWithParams(context,params,options);

        StartMeetingParamsWithoutLogin params = new StartMeetingParamsWithoutLogin();
        params.userId = usID; // Based on this id we are able to start the meeting as host
        params.userType = MeetingService.USER_TYPE_API_USER;
        params.displayName = userName;
        params.zoomAccessToken = zak; //getting the zoom access token from start_url
        params.meetingNo = meetingNumber; // meetingNo, getting this from create meeting api response
        ret = meetingService.startMeetingWithParams(context,params,options);
        Log.e("Start Meeting As Host", "===startMeetingWithNumber====ret=" + ret);
    }
```

i tried all generating more meeting using my web sdk but it wont work either

Comment: What are you seeing when running this code? Any error?

Comment: no errors, i just can't join the meeting as a host

Comment: Have you setup all your scopes and API's in Zoom.dev?